# MySQL Server version

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have this problem, on my website i try to comment on a profile page, but when i click to submit it, it says

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to, msg, author,time)
VALUES ('52', Test','Sakaio911', NOW())' at line 1
```

All I'm doing is inserting the comment into the database, and you can see what columns. Is it the NOW() that causes it because i have no idea what im doing wrong.

Comment: If you could post the exact query being performed, that would help.

Comment: PHP code for preparing insert query or debug and echo of full insert query may help.

Comment: 9/10 the issue is your query, not the mysql server version.

Comment: @JoseVega: 9/10?  I'd say more like 999999/1000000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message points you to the 'to' column name.  According to the documentation, that name is reserved as a key-word.  You will probably want to rename that col, or you will have to do some gymnastics to use that table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Use backticks or squared brackets to "escape" the column name.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't want to rename your column name, you must escape it in context by **`**

```
 ... `to`, msg, author, time) VALUES ('52', 'Test','Sakaio911', NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a semicolon both for the sql query and the php code line itself.One semicolon inside the " " marks and the other outside to terminate the line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the field names with back ticks ... so for example `to`,`msg` etc.  That should solve that particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ('52', Test','Sakaio911', NOW())'

The insert statement uses commas as delimiters for the field names and their values. It appears that you're missing something between the **'52'** and the **Test'**.
Are you short a single quote before **Test'** or should the entire string be in double quotes like this? **"This'"**.